# Radeon RX 5600 XT driver support

Tags: drivers, radeon

I am new to Ubuntu (19.10) and love it!
I read on a PC hardware supplier site that currently (mid-March 2020) there are no Linux drivers for the "6GB Sapphire Radeon RX 5600 XT Pulse Aktiv" graphics card.

- Is this true?
- Will there be a driver by the time Ubuntu 20.04 is
  released?
- Where would I find the driver?

NOTE: I have not purchased this graphics card yet, so I cannot test anything. I want to know if it is safe to make this purchase. My only requirement would be UHD (3840 x 2160) resolution on a single monitor. I am not a gamer but I watch videos (in Full HD).

**UPDATE:**

No Linux drivers for RX **5600** XT are listed here:
https://www.amd.com/en/support/graphics/amd-radeon-5600-series/amd-radeon-rx-5600-series/amd-radeon-rx-5600-xt

And under RX **5500** XT there is a driver for Ubuntu 18.04 and the Release Notes (under Product Compatibility) state it's for the "**AMD Radeon™ RX 5700/5500 Series Graphics**". So it seems that RX **5600** XT is unsupported.

Comment: My Radeon 5500 XT works automatically after upgrading to Ubuntu 20.04 LTS.

Comment: Sadly I have installed 18.04LTS, and it does not work out-of-the-box.   Always ending up with some crashes as described here:   https://tthtlc.wordpress.com/2020/05/09/solving-a-amd-graphics-card-radeon-rx-5600-xt-problem-with-ubuntu-18-04-2/.   And after I finally downloaded the latest stable kernel source code, recompile it - it worked.   Full details described above.

Comment: RX 5600 XT runs PERFECTLY on Ubuntu 20.04

Answer (score 0):

It is correct that there currently are no official drivers for the AMD 5600 XT on their website but, nonetheless, the open source AMDGPU drivers work just fine and I have no problem with the Graphics Card with two UHD 60fps screens.
My guess is, that they will ship the official driver with the official release of Ubuntu 20.04 LTS (April 23rd).